# Why is vm.nr_hugepages being overridden?

Tags: linux-kernel, centos7, huge-pages

I want to specify 25 off 1GB hugepages on our Centos 7 system, which has 48GB RAM.

I have specified the following boot parameters:

```
hugepagesz=1G hugepages=25 default_hugepagesz=1G
```

but after boot the system reports:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:      43
HugePages_Free:       43
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

I find that:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep nr
vm.nr_hugepages = 200
```

I tried setting vm.nr_hugepages = 25 directly and via a custom tuned profile (that includes 'balanced') but still vm.nr_hugepages gets set to 200.

So something, somewhere is overriding the value I set. What could this be?

Comment: Hello, did you find the answer? Was this something configured in a file in /etc/sysctl.d/* ?